# Magento 2 : System Configuration select email templates not working

Tags: magento2, configuration, email-templates

I'm trying to render a select field with email templates under Sytemem->Configuration
.
When i open the configuration tab it doenst show any config fields more.

Here are my files

> etc/system.xml

```
  <field id="pickup_template" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>New Order Confirmation Template for Guest</label>
                <comment>Email template chosen based on theme fallback when "Default" option is selected.</comment>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template</source_model>
  </field>
```

> etc/email_templates.xml

```
   <template id="pickup_template" label="New Order" file="yourfile.html" type="html" module="Hello_StorePickup" area="frontend"/>
```

> view/frontend/email/yourfile.html

```
    <b>message</b>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doenst show any config fields more"? Sounds like an exception that is thrown.

Comment: In log system.log show a error check it

Comment: @ND17 would you able to resolve that I have the same problem ??

Comment: you can check apache/server log if exception.log have no error

Answer (score 4):

Get `Section id` and `group id` of that field
For example `Section id= id1` and `group id = id2`

and your **etc/email_templates.xml** like this

```
  <template id="id1_id2_pickup_template" label="New Order" file="yourfile.html" type="html" module="Hello_StorePickup" area="frontend"/>
```